# React - setState not updating array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Here's my code :

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    query: '',
    results: []
  }
  handleSearch(e) {
    var query = e.target.elements.query.value;
   axios.get("http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=" + query + "&page=1&apikey=xxxx")
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        this.setState({
          results: response.data.Search
        });
      }.bind(this))
      .catch(function (error) {
      });
    e.preventDefault();
  }
```

I'm trying to fetch data from **omdb** and show it on page.

the problem is setState not updating an array `results`?

Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: If you write `console.error(error);` inside your `catch` function, does it log anything to the console? Do you get an error in the Network tab of your Developer Tools?

Comment: @Tholle yes ; the output is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
"

Comment: @Axnyff but I just bind it with .bind(this)

Comment: @Chino Alright. Then you most likely need to bind `handleSearch` to `this` in the constructor, or make `handleSearch` into a class property arrow function: `handleSearch = (e) => { ... };`

Comment: @Axnyff  `var self = this; self.setState({
          results: response.data.Search
        });` not working either

Comment: Did not see the bind call, sorry. as @Tholle said, you need to bind handleSearch also. How are you calling it ?

Comment: @Chino It's not the axios callback function that is the issue, it is the `handleSearch` function itself that doesn't have the `this` value you expect.

Comment: Yep , now it's working, so the right way is arrow function instead of writing many functions for binding on constructor. Right ?

Comment: It's a matter of preference. I personally like to use arrow functions since you most of the time can skip the constructor altogether that way.

Comment: Thank you so much guys, you can write it as answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bind the function called when the axios requests completes correctly, but you must also bind the `handleSearch` method itself. You could do this in the constructor, or use a class property arrow function instead:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    query: '',
    results: []
  }

  handleSearch = (e) => {
    // ...
  }
}
```